In Windows 11, why does Task Manager and Process Explorer disagree about resource usage?
In Windows 11, Task Manager and Process Explorer disagree about resource usage. I have noticed this on multiple devices.
Windows Task Manager tends to report higher CPU load and lower Memory pressure, while Process Explorer tends to report lower CPU usage and higher memory usage.
I have a screenshot illustrating what I mean by this attached here:

On the screenshot, the memory pressure is shown with the yellow arrows: Task Manager reports 16.8 GB used (mark 1). Process Explorer reports 23 GB used (mark 2).
Red arrows show CPU usage: Task manager reports 40% usage and the graph clearly shows around 30-40% sustained use for a long time (mark 3). Process Explorer reports CPU usage in the single digits. The specific number is not visible on the screenshot but the CPU histogram clearly shows very low CPU usage (mark 4).
While this screenshot was taken, the machine was not completely idle but was doing some regular office work (outlook, word, excel, Teams - open but not in a meeting) and some light web browsing.
What is the reason for this discrepancy?
Which of these tools are to be trusted?
One reason I could think of is that one of these might only be showing numbers for processes running as my user. However, I run both TM and PE as administrator.
I am trying to understand my resource utilization by using Task Manager (Windows built-in) and Process Explorer (Sysinternals tool provided by Microsoft).
I was expecting them to report similar numbers. I am aware that since these numbers are a snapshot in time, there might be slight differences between the numbers reported. But I would expect the numbers to be roughly similar. Especially over time.
